Exposing Kubernetes pods with TCP and UDP traffic
I'm writing a Kubernetes operator to deploy individual, dedicated game servers, inside the same cluster. What would be the best method for exposing these servers outside of the cluster?
Requirements

Servers must be individually addressable outside of the cluster. Dedicated game servers are isolated from each other and cannot be load balanced.
Support TCP and UDP protocols. These are the primary protocols that the games will be communicating with.
Manageable programatically. My custom resource is an individual server. Assocciating a server to something like an ingress is dangerous, as a single ingress resource contains the rules of other servers too.
Scale to the upper limits of Kubernetes.
Native to Kubernetes. This could be hosted anywhere, with no reliance on custom resources or tooling outside of my own project.

Ideas
I initially thought of an ingress. However, ingress listeners and rules are not separate resources from the ingress itself. Modifying these rules programatically per individual server, could be very dangerous. This is the same with the listeners on the new Gateway API too.
I looked at nodeports, but since the scope of nodeports are cluster wide, the theoretical limit per cluster is a single range of ports - far below 65535.
The closest I've gotten so far is clusterIps with externalIps. From what I'm reading, this seems to work in a similar way to a nodePort, but the scope is placed on the externalIps. This means I could distribute the servers across a number of externalIps, scaling much more than nodeports.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 49152
  externalIPs:
    - 198.51.100.32

I'm not sure if I'm misinterpreting the way that clusterIps and externalIps work.

Yes, using ExternalIps will get you what you want, assuming that you have the level of access that permits you to assign routeable ip addresses to cluster nodes. A more flexible solution would be to utilize a load balancer (e.g,. metallb), but (like an Ingress resource) this requires installing third-party software on your cluster.

Thanks for the reply @larsks! I wouldn't think it was the end of the world to use Gateway or Ingress controllers, if they suited my use case.
However, they are both primarily for HTTP traffic. Using TCP and UDP traffic on Loadbalancer, Ingress or Gateway, mean that listeners have to be created as part of the main resource. So multiple instances depend on the same resource. This is dangerous as the code will have to check the current listeners, add another for a new instance and apply the change; if there is an issue, it could effect all servers using the same LB, Ingress or Gateway.

"This is dangerous as the code will have to check the current listeners, add another for a new instance and apply the change" I don't follow you there, but it doesn't really matter. It sounds like you have a solution and you understand the technical tradeoffs in each case, so it's not clear what, if any, question remains here.

On the externalIP bit, I'm guessing these IPs have to be allocated outside of the cluster. So I add a public facing IP to some of my nodes, then these can be specified in the service?

That's correct.

Thanks for the help! I know that I'm very new to Kubernetes, so wondered if I actually had the right idea.
I would rather do some research before asking my question. Had I done no research at all, I would be criticized . Even still, I've done some research, and I'm being critisized anyway.

Sometimes the best solution is a simple one:
Use the hostPort field on a Pod’s Container specification.

This opens a port on the host Node and routes traffic to the container via iptables or ipvs, depending on host provider and/or network overlay.
We do this, since you really can’t use a LoadBalancer to route UDP packets to a specific game server instance, and you don’t want or need the hop (most of the time) – it’s much better to go directly to the node.

Like externalIP, this means that you need a publicly addressable Node.
I had this answered in the Kubernetes community forums by the top contributor to Agones which is very similar to my project.

service type:LoadBalancer is the best way to expose services externally. Set externalTrafficPolicy:Local to direct the traffic to those dedicated nodes. Check this out: https://docs.loxilb.io/k3s_quick_start_incluster/
